# getting 404 error from nginx for a route which is redirecting to a .html file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, nginx, devops

I have following route in nodejs

```
app.get('/admin', function (req, res) {
     console.log("CAME HERE");
     res.redirect('/login.html');
});
```

my nginx.conf looks like this

```
upstream dev{
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.abc.com;


    location /api {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
            proxy_pass http://dev;
    }

    location /admin {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
            proxy_pass http://dev;
    }
```

}

Now when I enter this URL in the browser `dev.abc.com/admin` , the page is getting redirected  to `http://dev.abc.com/login.html` but an error is shown on the browser as follows:

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.0.5
```

things are working fine with localhost.

I think there is something extra to be done from nginx side, not sure what.

Comment: where is login.html is actually located, is it in the `/public` folder or?

Comment: YES, it is located in /public folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current Nginx config is only set to serve the node process @port 3001, no mention of any static files.

```
# replace with your public directory path
root /www/data;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
}
```

Reference: [Serving Static Content](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#root-directory-and-index-files)